# Displaying A Queue Implemented with a Linked List from Rear to front

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

I am currently working on a project for class that requires me to implement a queue with a linked list without using a library.  So far my project is working perfectly but when I push_back() 1, 3, 5, 7 the screen displays it with the front of the queue on the left. I would prefer it to look Rear on the left such as REAR 7 5 3 1 FRONT.  What exactly am I missing here that would help me do this?

```
#include "queue.h"
#include <iostream>
Queue::Queue()
{
    queue_size = 0;
    front = 0;
    rear = 0;
}
Queue::~Queue()
{
    delete front;
    delete rear;
}

void Queue::push_back(int x)
{
    node * q = new node;
    q->data = x;
    q->next = 0;

    if(this->isEmpty())
    {
        front = q;
        front ->next = 0;
        rear = front;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->next = q;
        rear = rear->next;
        rear->next = 0;
    }
    queue_size = queue_size + 1;
}

void Queue::pop_front(int &num)
{
    node * temp;
    num = front->data;
    temp = front;
    front = front ->next;
    delete temp;
    queue_size = queue_size - 1;



}
bool Queue::isEmpty()
{
    if(front == 0)
        return true;

    else
        return false;

}

int Queue::ret_size()
{
    return queue_size;
}

void Queue::display()
{
   node * temp;
   temp = front;

   for(int i = 0; i < queue_size; i++)
   {
       std::cout<<temp->data<< " ";
       temp = temp->next;
   }
   std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: I see that you got an answer you needed below. However, I figured I would throw out the idea of changing your node class / struct. You could add another node* field called "prev" and implement the Queue using a Double linked List. This would allow you to use your rear pointer to walk through the Queue backwards. In practice this will run faster than using a recursive approach and you also avoid possible stack overflows. However, there is an extra 4 bytes used per node and logic for removing and adding nodes is slightly more complicated. Just another design you could consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable with recursion, and have some faith that your system has sufficient stack for the size of Queues you plan, this can work.

```
void Queue::display(void)
{
   node* temp;
   temp = front;

   if(temp)
      temp->displayR();

   std::cout<<"\n";
}

void Queue::displayR(void)
{
   if(m_next) 
      m_next->displayR(); // spin down to end of queue

   // now display the current data
   std::cout << data << "  "; // report end of queue first
}
```

FYI: on ubuntu 12.04 and 4 Gig of ram, I believe I do not experience stack overflows until more than 100K elements in the queue.  Your results will vary ...

---

If you don't have faith, simply transfer the contents of your queue into a vector, then show the vector contents in reverse.

And since it is easy, and you want to avoid using a library, simply use an array.

Comment: the queue is not going to be larger than 5 integers so this will work perfectly! thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you simply reverse the loop in display() so it starts at rear and moves towards the front?

Comment: could you provide an example as to how to do this? I am still a newbie at c++

Comment: What I was thinking of was replacing temp = front with temp = rear and temp = temp->next with temp = temp->prev. My apologies for the terse answer - I'm typing on a small tablet - hopefully that will be enough to help you sort it out.

Comment: I added a comment that talks about modifying the node object. The node may only have a "next" pointer... aka Single Linked List. However, if the node is changed and Queue logic updated, a Double Linked List can definitely be used along with the approach you outline. This is personally how I implemented my own Queue as well.